# try use sprintf in an string with a previously unknown size generate a free() invalid next size

Tags: c

I need to use sprintf in an string with a previously unknown size.
This works, but generates a warning/error in the console.
What is wrong here?

```
// request a dummy size
char* str = (char *)malloc(2);

// first pass, just to get the final size
int size =  sprintf(str,"init_display(%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)",width,height,glwidth,glheight,title);

// realloc to correct size
str = (char *)realloc(str,sizeof(char)*size);

// second pass , get the full string
sprintf(str,"init_display(%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)",width,height,glwidth,glheight,title);

// free after use
free(str);
```

This generate 2 errors:

```
Error in "foo" realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00007f6dc8009b70 ***
Error in "foo" free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007f6dc8009b70 ***
```

Comment: have a look at snprintf

Comment: You are destroying the area associated with memory that was allocated.  first sprintf replace `size=snprintf(NULL,0, "init_display(%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)",...)` and then `str=malloc(size+1);`

Comment: Try `snprintf()`, and note you can use it's return value to figure out how much space you need if the space you gave it isn't enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two problems in your code. First of all, your fist call to `sprintf` writes to a memory region too small. Doing that invokes undefined behavior which means that anything can start misbehaving and it does. The second one is that after `realloc` call the memory region is still not large enough - there is no place for ending `\0` character.

In order to fix that, use `snprint`, which is almost like `sprintf` but it takes one additional argument - `size` of allocated memory. It never writes more than this amount of characters to the buffer. It still, however, returns the number of characters that would be written if the buffer was large enough. Now, you can use realloc to resize the buffer to **one more byte** than the returned value.

Note that if you happen to use `gcc` and you don't care for portable code, you may use `asprintf` instead.

Comment: I have incorrectly assumed that sprintf don't corrupt or overload my buffer, and complete forget about the ending character, thanks

Comment: @stalux: There is no way `sprintf` could know what is size of the buffer which means there is no way to prevent it corrupting it. It's the same for all other calls that takes only pointer to a destination buffer (without it's size) as an argument (like `strcpy`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `snprintf()` to find out how much space you need. 
In Visual Studio there is `_snprintf()`:

```
char* str;
// get the size
int size =  _snprintf(NULL,0,"init_display(%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)",width,height,glwidth,glheight,title);
// allocate memory
str = (char *)malloc(size+1);
// get the string
sprintf(str,"init_display(%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)",width,height,glwidth,glheight,title);
// free after use
free(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf(str,"init_display(%d,...` over writes the 2 `char` allocation of `str`.

If one does not want to `sprintf()` twice, consider a buffer that is certainly over-sized, then `realloc()`.

```
static const char format[] = "init_display(%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)";
size_t siz = sizeof(format) + 4*(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3) + strlen(title) + 1;

char *str = malloc(siz);
assert(str != NULL);
siz = sprintf(str, format, width, height, glwidth, glheight, title) + 1;

char *str2 = realloc(str, siz);
assert(str2);
str = str2;

// free after use
free(str);
```

@Krzysztof Adamski answer is less error prone as with this approach, code needs to absolutely correctly calculate the maximum buffer size.